# Output my XML schema to HTML

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a schema generator that uses an XmlSchema to build an xml based on an EF model.

My problem is, I would like to return the XMLschema in a human readable format so I can display it in HTML to an the end user.

I've tried using toString(), however this doesn't work. What would be the best way to return my XMLSchema?

The xml formats correctly, I guess I just don't know how to return it to the frontend so I can wrap it in highlighting

Code Below:

```
 public ActionResult ResourceXML(int id)
    {
        Resource res = db.Resources.Find(id);
        res.Properties = db.ResourceProperties.Where(c => c.ResourceId == id).ToList();

        XmlSchema schema = new XmlSchema();
        XmlSchemaElement resource = new XmlSchemaElement();

        schema.Namespaces.Add("hrr", "http://schema.hrr.com/hrr");
        schema.Namespaces.Add("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        schema.TargetNamespace = "http://www.w3schools.com";

        resource.Name = res.Name;
        resource.SchemaTypeName = new XmlQualifiedName("string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        resource.Id = ""+res.Id;

        //annotation
        XmlSchemaAnnotation resourceAnno = new XmlSchemaAnnotation();
        resource.Annotation = resourceAnno;

        //documentation
        XmlSchemaDocumentation docs = new XmlSchemaDocumentation();
        resourceAnno.Items.Add(docs);
        docs.Markup = TextToNodeArray(""+res.Description);

        //complex type
        XmlSchemaComplexType complexType = new XmlSchemaComplexType();

        //sequence
         XmlSchemaSequence sequence = new XmlSchemaSequence();
        complexType.Particle = sequence;

        foreach (var property in res.Properties)
        {
            XmlSchemaElement element = new XmlSchemaElement();

            element.Name = property.Name;
            element.SchemaTypeName = new XmlQualifiedName(GetTheType(property), "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            element.Id = property.Id+"";

            if (property.Required)
            {
                element.MinOccurs = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                element.MinOccurs = 0;
            }

            if (property.List)
            {
                element.MaxOccursString = "unbounded";
            }
            else
            {
                element.MaxOccursString = "1";
            }
            //annotation
            XmlSchemaAnnotation elemAnno = new XmlSchemaAnnotation();
            element.Annotation = elemAnno;

            //documentation
            XmlSchemaDocumentation elemDoc = new XmlSchemaDocumentation();
            resourceAnno.Items.Add(elemDoc);
            //No property data
            elemDoc.Markup = TextToNodeArray("");

            sequence.Items.Add(element);
        }

        schema.Items.Add(resource);
        schema.Version = "" + res.Version.Number;
      //schema.Write(stream:);
        return File(stream, "text/xml");

    }
```

Comment: I have used HtmlTextWriter to output my XML to HTML. This is if you want more control over the presentation of your XML using HTML tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write it to a stream and return the stream.

For example,

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
schema.Write(ms);
ms.Flush();
return new FileStreamResult(ms, "text/xml");
```

Comment: Ahh, I always am over cautious about disposing...  I'll edit ti reflect not disposing it.  Glad it helped.